# I want to get good knowledge in vb.net,Share point.Can you guide me which book is best to learn vb.net as a expert?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, vb.net-2010

I have 1.7 +Years of experience in .Net web application.
I want to get good knowledge in vb.net ,Share point ,So Please guide me how to learn and which book is best for learning so that i can compare myself 3-4 years of experienced person  in in vb.net and share point.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are new bee, welcome to coding world :)

You can pick on for sharepoint
Sharepoint 2010 Microsoft 2010 unleashed from Sams publishing
Building solutions for SharePoint 2010 by Sohil Malik
Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010 from Microsoft Press

Try for asp.net rather than vb.net ;)

All the best,
Adi
You can check by blog for some basics : [AdiCodes](http://adicodes.wordpress.com/)